# sets in linux Bash

Tags: linux, bash, collections, set

Wonder whether we have sets in linux Bash or how to implement this in most clean and efficient way. Any suggestions? Thanks.
Clarification:
The task:
We have names in a text file.
We want to create a set of names.
That is: if the name is listed more than once, we want to have only one entry for this.
Example: text file contains: 'Anna' 'John' 'Anna'
We want to get the output: 'Anna' 'John' (in any order)
Technology: Bash
In languages like Java I would use set for this. In Bash I've only come accross arrays and dictionaries (called associative array). Dictionary can serve as a set, would prefer to have a set though, as this is a more simple structure.

Comment: Did you try googling? Apparently bash does support [one-dimensional arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: One-dimensional arrays are not a good way to implement sets.

Comment: Sets of what? Strings? Integers? And you write "sets (collections)"; what does the word "collections" add here? Are you sure you're entirely clear on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

*bash* has *associative arrays*, that can also be used for sets. Here is a short example:

```
declare -A names
names['Mickey']=1
names['Donald']=1

for name in Mickey foobar; do
    if [[ -n "${names[$name]}" ]]; then
         echo "$name exists."
    fi
done
```